# Test ads aren't showing in my android phone after I "build and run" it in unity

Tags: admob, android-manifest, manifest, ads

really need your help.
Just added AdMob to my project.
I try to make my test ads to show but they aren't showing after i build and run my game to my phone.
in the in the console said the following lines after I press button to show the banner view:
dummy .octr 
dummy CeateBannerView
dmmy LoadAD
dummy ShowBannnerView
Please note that I'm using sample AppID and sample banner and sample interstitial !

Answer (score 0):

Good news, if you are getting the dummy responses in the debug console then you have configured everything correctly. I had this same problem when I first implemented ads in my game. It turns out that you may have to wait up to 3 days for the ads to actually start showing on your device depending on how long it takes for AdMob to set up your account.

Comment: Hi, I wish it was good news but I afraid that's not the truth. because I jus download console debugger, and I get the following errors: 1. AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds .                                                             2.AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.ads.UnityAdListerner

Comment: Here you go: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1464677/admob-plugin-error-javalangclassnotfoundexception.html